# What does Cellular Automata Pre-image problem actually means?

Tags: finite-automata, np-complete, cellular-automata

I am reading about Cellular Automata and Computational Complexity and i found a related paper by F. Green, [NP-Complete Problems in Cellular Automata](http://www.complex-systems.com/pdf/01-3-4.pdf).

In the 2nd page he lists three NP-Complete problems related to CA, the first  problem is:

> CA preimage : Given a subconfiguration of length $K$, is there a configuration that could have led to it in $K$ time steps ?

I am confused with the term "Sub-configuration" and its meaning, in the paper he states that a Sub-configuration is *contagious states in a finite array*.

1- Does it mean a structure like Rule 110 or 90 - ECA at length $K$ ?

2- Or does it mean a pattern generated after $K$ time step in a specific structure (i.e a pattern in rule 110) ?

3- Why the problem states that the subconfiguration's length should equal to the time steps it was generated in ?  what if the problem was solvable in $K$ time steps but with a constant time steps $Z$ ?

Comment: read carefully p2: a configuration is an infinite string/ tape sequence and a subconfiguration is finite. these are not generally std terms in the field however. anyway $K$ is a count of cells and also time steps. its just a bound, it can be generalized ($K \neq Z)$ to different step/ cell differences based on "padding" technique typically.

Comment: So i can say the pre-image problem is nothing but a simulation of other structures in CA (generally) right ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way I understand it, the answer is your item #2.

That is, the specific CA is *fixed* (i.e., rule 90 or rule 110, or what ever), and given that fixed CA, one gives you a (sub)configuration, and asks whether there exists another configuration that leads to the input (sub)configuration within $K$ steps.

Indeed the description there (in the introduction of the paper) is very informal, but this is only because the 
the problem is formally stated in section 3:

> **CAP (CA Preimage problem)**:
>   **Given**: A fixed CA $(Q,\delta)$ and a configuration substring $s$.
>   **Question**: Is there a configuration substring $s_0$ such that $s_0 \vdash^{K} s$, where $K= |s|$?

Comment: Thanks Ran it is more easy to understand now (hope the question gets solved someday) ...